# combine list values with common keys to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the a list like

{
'person1', 'Hi',
'person1', 'You there?',
'person2', 'Hello',
'person1', 'Hru?',
'person2'','Good'
}

How do i convert this into a dictionary by grouping keys and combining text values?
Expected result:

{'person1': 'Hi You there? Hru?',
'person2': 'Hello Good'}

NOTE: The grouping should be done using the key names. As the conversation isn't always person1 followed by person2.

The code from aniketh seems to work. I now need to apply this on a dataframe which has many of this lists.

```
      chatid   list_of_convo
--------------------------------------------------------------------
0     12         {'person1', 'Hi','person1', 'You there?','person2', 
                  'Hello','person1', 'Hru?','person2','Good'}
1     21          {'person3', 'Hi','person3', 'You there?','person2', 
                   'Hello','person3', 'Hru?','person2','Good'}
2     34          {'person5', 'Hi','person5', 'You there?','person2', 
                   'Hello','person5', 'Hru?','person2','Good'}
```

The answer to above is:

```
def Convert(lst):
    dct = {}
    for ind in range(len(lst)):
      if ind % 2 == 0:
        if lst[ind] not in dct:
          dct[lst[ind]] = ""

    for ind in range(len(lst)):
      if ind % 2 == 1:
        dct[lst[ind - 1]] += lst[ind] + " "

    return dct

df['grouped'] = df['list_of_convo'].apply(Convert)
```

(For other's reference)

Comment: Your initial list is malformed

Comment: May I know which part seems malformed?
you may ignore the colons inside the list values in the list.

I made the edit.

Comment: `{ 'person1', 'Hi', 'person1', 'You there?', 'person2', 'Hello', 'person1', 'Hru?', 'person2'','Good' }` is not a valid python list and it appears to include some typos.

Comment: What have you tried? That's not a list

Comment: The question should not be evolving all the time. Ask a separate question.

Comment: Create another question

Comment: Thank you all. The question has been answered by aniketh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code could work:

```
lst = [ 'person1:', 'Hi', 'person2:', 'Hello', 'person1:', 'Hru?', 'person2:','Good' ]

dct = {}
for ind in range(len(lst)):
  if ind % 2 == 0:
    if lst[ind] not in dct:
      dct[lst[ind]] = ""

for ind in range(len(lst)):
  if ind % 2 == 1:
    dct[lst[ind - 1]] += lst[ind] + " "

print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'person1:': 'Hi Hru? ', 'person2:': 'Hello Good '}
```

First, to initialize a list, we use `[]` instead of `{}`

After we make our dictionary, `dct`, we can iterate through every even indexed element of `lst` to get the elements (`'people1'`, `'people2'`) that will be the keys of `dct`. First, we check if the key already exists in `dct`, and if not, we add it in.

Finally, we iterate through the odd indexed elements and concatenate them to the values of their respective keys (the element before them in `lst`).

I hope this helped! Please let me know if you need any further help or clarification!

Note: If you care about the extra space in the output, add the following code segment before you print to get rid of the extra space:

```
for key, value in dct.items():
  dct[key] = value[:-1]
```

Second Input:

`lst = ['person1', 'Hi', 'person1', 'You there?', 'person2', 'Hello', 'person1', 'Hru?', 'person2','Good' ]`

Output:

`{'person1': 'Hi You there? Hru?', 'person2': 'Hello Good'}`

Comment: Added a comment. I do not want to iterate based on the indices. As the order of person1 and person2 can change. person1 can appear twice consecutively just like a normal  conversation. I'll update the data in the question to avoid this confusion.

Comment: Yes, the code still works in that case @Shay

Comment: As long as the user (people1, people2) and their messages alternate, the code will work, the actual order of users does not affect the code

Comment: ok thanks that seem to work.
Do you happen to know how to apply this on a data frame now?

I have a data frame with columns of chatid,list of convo.
The example above was just extracted from one chatid's list of convo.
I have 100s of chatids each with a list like above in a dataframe.

Comment: I have updated the question to indicate how the dataframe looks like and i need to apply this logic to that dataframe for each chatid.

Comment: @Shay see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pairs = zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2])
mydict = {}

for k, v in pairs:
   mydict[k] = (mydict.get(k, '') + ' ' + v).strip()
```

my_list[::2] will get every other element of the list starting at the first element (which should be your keys).  my_list[1::2] will do the same but starting on the second element and this should be your values. zip() will make a list of tuples that pair each key and value. Then the last line just parses that list of key-value tuples into an actual dict based on your requirements around repeat keys.

Comment: Just added a comment. grouping should be done based on the values and not its indices.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean — this will always work if the list is formatted such that even indices (0,2,4) are keys and odd indices are values.  Do you want content to be added to the dictionary if a repeat key is found? Edit: I see what you mean, sorry, will see if I can add that

Comment: yes if repeat keys are found. So, indices here cannot be considered.

Comment: I have changed the answer to append to the result of .get() which can return an empty string if the key isn’t in the dictionary yet. I think it should work now, but I am not sure what your objection is around indices. Could you provide some other sample data that shows why indexing won’t work?